# RoomProcessor compilation or a circular dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've been struggling for days with and issue with Android Room component.

All I did was upgrade my Android studio from 3.3 to 3.4.1, this comes with changes to gradle etc that are done. 
I've even tried going back to 3.3, but nothing is working. 
I've have run with `Run with --info or --debug option` to try see more details but nothing gives me more info. Please help

```
e: /.../app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/.../model/HotspotEntity.java:7: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public final class HotspotEntity implements android.os.Parcelable {
             ^
e: /.../app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/.../ConditionEntity.java:7: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor "same as above".
public final class ConditionEntity implements android.os.Parcelable {
             ^
e: /.../app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/.../model/AdLimits.java:6: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor "same as above"
public final class AdLimits {
             ^
e: /.../app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/.../model/AdTarget.java:6: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor "same as above"
public final class AdTarget {
             ^
e: /.../app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/.../model/AdUrl.java:6: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor "same as above"
public final class AdUrl {
             ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Versions

```
Android Gradle:
3.4.1
Gradle version:
5.4.1
Android Room:
def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha06"
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:' + room_version
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:' + room_version
testImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:' + room_version
```

----UPDATE----

Below was tried with room `2.1.0-rc01"`which changed it to the same problem but for a different class:

```
AppDatabase.java:8: error: [RoomProcessor:MiscError] androidx.room.RoomProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract class AppDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
```

Grade File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cfl.surfstoked"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.4"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

    def lifecycleVersion = "2.1.0-alpha02"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:' + lifecycleVersion
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:' + lifecycleVersion
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:' + lifecycleVersion

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //DI
    def koinVersion = "1.0.2"
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:' + koinVersion
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:' + koinVersion
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:' + koinVersion

    //Navigation
//    def navigationVersion = "1.0.0-beta02"
//    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:' + navigationVersion
//    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:' + navigationVersion

    def navigationVersion = "2.1.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:' + navigationVersion
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:' + navigationVersion

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    //Coroutines
    def corutinesVersion = "1.1.1"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:' + corutinesVersion
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:' + corutinesVersion

    //Database
    def room_version = "2.1.0-rc01"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:' + room_version
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:' + room_version
//    implementation 'androidx.room:room-coroutines:' + room_version
    testImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:' + room_version

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

app dependencies

```
debugCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'debug' (target  (androidJvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:{strictly 1.3.30} -> 1.3.30 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:{strictly 1.3.30} -> 1.3.30 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:{strictly 1.3.30} -> 1.3.30 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:{strictly 1.3.30} -> 1.3.30 (c)
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:{strictly 1.0.2} -> 1.0.2 (c)
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:{strictly 1.1.0-rc01} -> 1.1.0-rc01 (c)
+--- androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.1.0-alpha05} -> 1.1.0-alpha05 (c)
+--- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:{strictly 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava} -> 9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:{strictly 2.1.0-beta01} -> 2.1.0-beta01 (c)
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:{strictly 1.1.0-alpha02} -> 1.1.0-alpha02 (c)
+--- androidx.collection:collection:{strictly 1.1.0-alpha03} -> 1.1.0-alpha03 (c)
+--- androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:{strictly 1.0.0-alpha02} -> 1.0.0-alpha02 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:{strictly 2.1.0-beta01} -> 2.1.0-beta01 (c)
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:{strictly 1.1.0-alpha05} -> 1.1.0-alpha05 (c)
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.customview:customview:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.loader:loader:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.activity:activity:{strictly 1.0.0-alpha05} -> 1.0.0-alpha05 (c)
+--- androidx.savedstate:savedstate:{strictly 1.0.0-alpha02} -> 1.0.0-alpha02 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:{strictly 2.2.0-alpha01} -> 2.2.0-alpha01 (c)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:{strictly 2.1.0-alpha02} -> 2.1.0-alpha02 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:{strictly 1.1.1} -> 1.1.1 (c)
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.2} -> 1.0.2 (c)
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
+--- androidx.print:print:{strictly 1.0.0} -> 1.0.0 (c)
...
+--- androidx.room:room-runtime:{strictly 2.1.0-rc01} -> 2.1.0-rc01 (c)
+--- androidx.room:room-common:{strictly 2.1.0-rc01} -> 2.1.0-rc01 (c)
+--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:{strictly 2.0.1} -> 2.0.1 (c)
+--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:{strictly 2.0.1} -> 2.0.1 (c)
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:{strictly 4.7.1} -> 4.7.1 (c)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.30
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.30
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.30
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.30
...
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1 (*)
+--- androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-rc01
|    +--- androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-rc01
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-rc01
|    +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.0.1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2 -> 1.1.0-rc01
|    |    \--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1
|    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2 -> 1.1.0-rc01
|    +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0-beta01 (*)
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0-alpha05 (*)
|    \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0-alpha03 (*)
```

Comment: Try this, delete   `build`, `.gradle `, `.idea`  folders . Do not build project , Click on invalidate cache and restart .

Comment: @ManoharReddy thanks but that didn't help, still the same issue.

Comment: @cfl Can you please share your gradle file?
Also, did you try running : `./gradlew app:dependencies` to check out the dependency tree. Can you share the output of this as well.

Comment: @raxerz Thanks, I've made changes to question. It went over character limit so had to remove some code, tried to only remove what seems none relevant. If the above doesn't help will add more back.

Comment: When you open the problematic classes with Android Studio, do you see any errors there. Anyhow it might be related to global caching of KAPT as well. Would it work with a completely clean build on some CI?

Comment: any news on that? I also wasted days in investigating this damn issue :-/

Comment: @m.zander Thank you for your efforts. I'm still stuck. But thought about a few things I can try, will hopefully have something to report back at the end.

Comment: After days I found that I was able to compile again after switching back to Gradle plugin v3.2.2

Comment: @m.zander thats great, will also try that. Was this with android studio 3.4? or 3.3?

Comment: 3.4 but I have got the same issue on 3.6 from the canary channel

Comment: @cfl Can you post the code of `AppDatabase` class and one entity model `Hotspot` since it is on the top of error list.

Answer (score 4):

From the initial lookup some of your dependencies are old. Please try the following setup ran and tested by me.

**Android Studio : 3.4.1**

**build.gradle (project)**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha05"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //DI
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:1.0.2'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'

    //Database
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Changed the navigation gradle safe args, lifecycle viewmodels, and room versions. All others were the same. Sadly still have the same issue, I cleaned etc. Thanks though. Is this build working for you?

Comment: Ai this sucks. Appreciate though. I will keep trying other changes around this setting. Hopefully come right.

Comment: Can you please try downloading the new Android Studio and setting up everything from scratch? Also delete the .android & .gradle folder.

Comment: that you for the suggestion. I tried that, still have the same problem.

Comment: @cfl Do one last favor, please upload the project to github without any .xml and .java/.kt files. I want to run the exact same project in my system.

Comment: thank you for being willing to do that, but for IP reasons I cannot share the project. Sorry, appreciate your willingness to assist. Another developer working on the project does have the same issue on his machine

Comment: the problem seems to be independent of the developers machine.
In our company we can reproduce the error also on all machines that tries to run the 'broken' project.,

Answer (score 2):

I had run into the same problem, and comparing the OP's gradle file with mine, I found that both contained

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

By removing it, Room's annotation processing started to work.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve my issue. Thank you though. Hope it helps someone else

Comment: I actually thought I had deleted this but it was in a window for another project. Thanks, this helped me. I also deleted all my room dependencies and added them one-by-one and turns out I didn't need half of them anymore. Tip: if you need `room-ktx` for coroutines, then it has most of everything else as a transitive dependency. My room section is now only 2 lines: `room-ktx` and the kapt line.

Answer (score 1):

You commented out the `room-coroutines` dependency, but I'd assume you didn't change your actual implementation. This dependency was not removed, but rather renamed to `room-ktx`. So just add it to enable the *Coroutine* support for *Room*.

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:' + room_version
```

Comment: Thank you @tynn we aren't using it but maybe in the future. But is useful to know thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider trying the following:

Remove any room related dependencies with these ones, which are the latest ones per:  [The Room Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room)

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
```

Second thing to consider is that you are duplicating dependencies with different versions, you might get issues when the build system tries to perform its dependency resolution and lead to misleading errors, for example:

```
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
```

One should be enough, preferably the stable one.

If you need information about dependencies and migrating some to androidx as well [here is the migrating to androidx guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work for me, but I might be missing something. I've given up on this issue though, wasted weeks of life on it.

Answer (score 1):

For all those can't compile here is a little (hopefully temporary) workarround.

If you switch back the gradle version to `3.3.2` android studio should compile a usual and you can leave all other dependencies as they are or update them.

**That setup works for me:**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.0"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could fix it just updating the DB version:

```
@Database(
    entities = [...],
    version = 4, exportSchema = true
)
```

The problem is because the autogenerated schemas, another solution could be deleting your old schemas in `schemas` folder in your project but can cause a bit of trouble if your app is in production.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve my issue. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Had kinda the same issue and the following annotations exclusions under dependencies (don't know why anymore)

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
}
```

Removed it and it worked. Maybe that helps you?

Answer (score 1):

You must include the library:

```
implementation org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:19.0.0
```

Because the code which is generated out of the annotations through the `kapt` plugin, uses `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` annotation.

It you copy-paste the generated java class is your classpath, you will see the compilation error.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating room version to "2.1.0-rc01".

```
def room_version = "2.1.0-rc01"
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I tried updating it seemed to have removed some of the above issues but not all, the "AppDatabase.java:8: error: 'same as above' " still remains.

Comment: @cfl - Did you try invalidate cache and restart in android studio after updating?

Comment: yes I did, thanks. Ai really wasted days on this issue, appreciate your input so far. Let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: @cfl - remove apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' and clean and sync project.

Comment: Thank you, I removed it - the same issue is happening though. I did all the cleans etc. Out of interest what lead you to suggest removing that? I thought it was needed

Comment: that does sadly not resolve the problem. It is still on version `2.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. 
Occured after I fetched project from my github.
Dependencies/versions changes had no effect.
What i did is deleted all branches on GitHub except the primary one, and created new project from the remaining branch.
Issue is gone out of the box.